# Single reference split in two columns

Tags: bibliographies, multicol

I need to represent the references of an article class document in 2 columns. I am using the `natbib` package.
The code I am using is:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{multicols}
```

As a result, a single reference gets split into 2 columns, which is not what I want. One entry of the reference list must remain inside one column. I checked some other posts, none could help me.

Comment: How many lines does the reference in question span? By the way, which document class do you employ?

Comment: It spans 4 lines. I am using article class.

Comment: Does loading the `etoolbox` and `needspace` packages and running `\pretocmd{\bibitem}{\Needspace*{4\baselineskip}{}{}` (in the preamble) fix the problem? Aside: Do your bibliography feature entries with fewer than 3 lines?

Comment: @Mico Many thanks. It works better now. The only detail I would like to correct is the fact that the second column starts with an entry that stands at the same height as the 'References' section, whereas the first entry of the first column stands 3 lines below that level. Can one level the first entries of the two columns up to the same height ?

Comment: That's an issue that's completely separate from the one so far, and one that I believe cannot be solved with your current setup, *viz.*, the `multicols` environment. At any rate, I cannot imagine that the readers of your document will care one whit about how the bibliographic material is distributed across the two columns.